# Rails nested attributes type mispatch error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rails-activerecord, nested-attributes

I am creating a **rails api** using [`rails_api gem`](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api), I have a model name `User` and another model named `Identity`.

The issue I am facing is that whenever I tries to create user from params with `nested_attributes` it gives me `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch error`

***Models***

**User.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    enum gender: [:male , :female]
    has_many :identities ,dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :identities
    has_secure_password
end
```

**Identity.rb**

```
class Identity < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    validates_associated :user
end
```

***Controllers***

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

def create      
    @user = User.new user_params
    #@user.build.identities(user_params[:identities])
    if @user.save
        render json: @user , status: :created
    else
        render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
end

private
def user_params
    json_params = ActionController::Parameters.new( JSON.parse(request.body.read) )
    json_params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :image, :location, :gender,{identities: [:provider, :uid, :url, :token, :expires_at]})
end
```

end

I am sending the data as json object:

[image: Request body]

This is the error in server console:
[image]

Kindly help me fix this issue. I have tried all the possible solutions. Thanks in advance

Comment: I think it's because you are just sending an array to the identities attribute ! You have to give to the identities attribute an Identity Record !

Comment: Don't you think `json_params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :image, :location, :gender,{identities: [:provider, :uid, :url, :token, :expires_at]})` should be `json_params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :image, :location, :gender,identities_attributes: [:provider, :uid, :url, :token, :expires_at])` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your strong param should be like this:

```
json_params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :image, :location, :gender,identities_attributes: [:provider, :uid, :url, :token, :expires_at])
```

Comment: I have changed strong param but `Unpermitted parameter: identities error` occurs.

Comment: you should be sending array of identities in params
identities_attributes: [{ }]

Answer (score 0):

```
json_params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :image, :location, :gender, :identities => [:provider, :uid, :url, :token, :expires_at])
```

this will resolve your issue as in current way.